# recursion with several functions F#

Tags: f#

I need some help with my hometask: to express one function (sort) through others (smallest, delete, insert). If you know how, please, tell me, how I can do running my recursion cicle? it doing now only one step. maybe something like this: val4 -> head :: tail |> sort tail on line 25 (val4)?

```
let rec smallest = function
  | x :: y :: tail when x <= y -> smallest (x :: tail)
  | x :: y :: tail when x > y -> smallest (y :: tail)
  | [x] -> Some x
  | _ -> None

let rec delete (n, xs) =
  match (n, xs) with
  | (n, x :: xs) when n <> x -> x :: delete (n, xs)
  | (n, x :: xs) when n = x -> xs
  | (n, _) -> []

let rec insert (xs, n) =
  match (xs, n) with
  | ([x], n) when x < n -> [x]@[n]
  | (x :: xs, n) when x < n -> x :: insert (xs, n)
  | (x :: xs, n) when x >= n -> n :: x :: xs
  | (_, _) -> []

let rec sort = function
  | xs -> let val1 = smallest xs
          let val2 = val1.[0]
          let val3 = delete (val2, xs)
          let val4 = insert (val3, val2)
          val4
let res = sort [5; 4; 3; 2; 1; 1]
printfn "%A" res
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sort of like insertion sort, but since you're always finding the smallest number in the whole list instead of the next highest number, it will recurse forever unless you skip whatever you've already found to be the smallest.

Furthermore, your insert and delete functions act not on the item index, but on equality to the value, so it won't be able to handle repeated numbers.

Keeping most of your original code the same, usually you have an inner recursive function to help you keep track of state. This is a common FP pattern.

```
let sort lst = 
        let size = lst |> List.length
        let rec sort' xs = function
            | index when index = size -> xs
            | index -> 
                let val1 = smallest (xs |> List.skip index)
                let val2 = val1.[0]
                let val3 = delete (val2, xs)
                let val4 = insert (val3, val2)
                sort' val4 (index + 1)
        sort' lst 0

let res = sort [5; 3; 2; 4; 1; ]
printfn "%A" res
```

Needless to say, this isn't correct or performant, and each iteration traverses the list multiple times. It probably runs in cubic time.
But keep learning!

Answer (score 0):

I found it... I only had changed 4 & 5 lines above in the "smallest" on this: | [x] -> Some x
  | _ -> None, when there was: | [x] -> [x]
  | _ -> []

```
let rec sort = function
  | xs -> match xs with
          | head :: tail -> let val1 = smallest xs
                            match val1 with
                            | Some x -> let val2 = delete (x, xs)
                                        let val3 = insert (val2, x)
                                        let val4 = (fun list -> match list with head :: tail -> head :: sort tail | _ -> []) 
                                        val4 val3
                            | None -> []
          | _ -> []
// let res = sort [5; 4; 3; 2; 1]
// printfn "%A" res
```